# find maximum of $| f(z) |$ in n $[0,2\pi] \times [0, 2\pi]$ for $f(z)=1+\sin^2(z). $

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Find the maximum of $|f(z)|$ in $[0,2\pi] \times [0, 2\pi]$ for

$$f(z)=1+\sin^2(z). $$

It is obvious to use maximum principle to do that. But I find the expression of the $|f(z)|$ is very complicated and it requires lots of computational work to obtain the answer.

So could anyone provide some insights of easy ways to solve this?

Many thanks.

Comment: You mean $[0,2\pi]\times [0,2\pi] \subset \Bbb{C}$? I don't think that is the boundary of a region.

Comment: @JoaquinLiniado, hi, yes. Actually the meaning is that $z=x+iy$, and both $x$ and $y$ belong to $[0,2\pi]$

Comment: Oh yes! My bad!